# appdesigner listbox item does not recognize HTML tags

Tags: html, matlab, user-interface, listbox

Unfortunately, this command does not change the color of the first item (named "XXX") in my appdesigner UI Liastbox!

```
app.ListBox_Test.Items{1} = '<html><font color="red"> XXX </font></html>'
```

This link clarifies that this feature is still not availble in appdesgner for liastbox:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/404134-different-colors-for-each-item-in-listbox-of-an-app-designer#comment_578148

Any syggestion or work around to make this feature work in appdesigner?